# How to vertically align in a react-grid-system row?

Tags: css, reactjs, vertical-alignment, react-grid-layout

I am using [react-grid-system](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-grid-system) with an image and two columns for text as follows:

```html
<Row>
  <Col md={1}>
    <img src=".." />
  </Col>
  <Col md={4}>
    .....
  </Col>
  <Col md={7}>
    ....
  </Col>
</Row>
```

In this, I want the image and all the text to be vertically in the middle of the row. I read the documentation [here](https://sealninja.github.io/react-grid-system/) but wasn't able to find anything related to vertical alignment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is vertical alignment in the docs it states for vertical alignment to use the align prop

```
  <Row align="center" style={{ height: '75px' }} debug>
    <Col debug>1 of 3</Col>
    <Col debug>2 of 3</Col>
    <Col debug>3 of 3</Col>
  </Row>
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you should add justify attribute to Row Element with "center" value like this:-

```
    <Row justify="center">
<Col xs={3} debug>1 of 3</Col>
<Col xs={3} debug>2 of 3</Col>
<Col xs={3} debug>3 of 3</Col>
</Row>
```

Comment: it probably is align instead justify ;)

Comment: This wasn't working but the other answer worked, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

try

```
<div class="i-am-centered">
<Row>
  <Col md={1}>
    <img src=".." />
  </Col>
  <Col md={4}>
    .....
  </Col>
  <Col md={7}>
    ....
  </Col>
</Row>
</div>
```

and for styling :

```
<style>
.i-am-centered { margin: auto; max-width: 300px;}
  </style>
```

Answer (score 1):

It helps in responsive design

```
<div style={{display:'grid',placeContent:"center"}}>
    <Row>
      <Col md={1}>
        <img src=".." />
      </Col>
     <Col md={4}>
       .....
     </Col>
     <Col md={7}>
       ....
     </Col>
    </Row>
</div>
```